# Jittered map in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want a jittered map for 244 values that are overlapping. I've a separate field calculation for the jittered_latitude and jittered_longitude. When I put in the these calculations in the row and column shelves, I get the first image that follows. When I try to map these values I get the second image. I want to get the jittered values in the map(organised in circle), which I do not get. Can someone please help me?

[image]

Edit: I did not rename my row/column shelf from the jittered names. When I try to use the map with the jittered values it automatically changes the row/coloumn shelf to the new name. The color and text icon also gets added automatically. When I remove them manually I get this image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY9Mm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, you seem to use different Lat/Long values in your map (picture 2) than you do in your test worksheet (picture 1).
If you replace these with your `[jittered_latitude], [jittered_longitude]` and make sure that all other pills are at the same spots on your dashboard and are assigned to the same properties.
So for example in your map you have `[jittered_latitude], [jittered_longitude]` assigned to colour and size. If that's not what you want, left click on the small icon left of the pill and choose whatever property you want it to be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You got the circles, however, your graph has x-axis and y-axis instead of longitude and latitude. It seems like you did not assign geographical roles to your "jittered_latitude" and "jittered_longitude".

Take the variables off the shelves, do the following, then put them back in the shelves.

Right-click on "jittered_latitude", select "Geographical Role" from the pop-up menu, then select "latitude". Repeat this process for "jittered_longitude", except that the "Geographic Role" should be "longitude".

Also, make sure that your table calculations (z_spread_direction, jittered_latitude, jittered_longitude) are edited in the following way.

I cannot attach the picture here, but this is how all three of your table calculations need to be edited.

1. Choose "Specific Dimensions". 2. Select all items. 3. Choose Zip Code for "At the level". 4. Choose City for "Restarting every".

Also, you do not need "jittere_latitude" and "jittered_longitude" in Marks card, but you do need to place "renamed_latitude" and "renamed_longitude" there.